# How can I check where one schema is referred in OpenAPIs?

Tags: swagger, openapi, jsonschema, openapi-generator

I am working on about 100 APIs in OpenAPIs, and I have about 200 to 300 component schemas, some of them are referred at multiple places which reduces redundancy. But I am confused while making changes to them, because one specific change would reflect in all schemas which is not good. Is there any way on Swagger that I can see where that schema is being referred, so i can avoid undesired changes?

Comment: Have you considered opening the containing folder in an IDE and doing a project/folder wide search?

Comment: @Relequestal Didn't get it? Although i have came up with a technique to find ref by searching for reference string ''#/components/schemas/object'' in yaml document. This will show where is that component is referred, but that is still a way arround

Comment: Right. Searching the files. How else would you expect to do it?